# How to bring xlwings excel file foreground using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlwings

I am using xlwings to modify an excel file in Python 3.6. xlwings opens the excel instance and runs my python script, as a results the Excel file would go to the background of my pycharm window.

Is there any straightforward way to bring the excel file to the foreground at the end of the program?

My code is similar to this:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('Excel.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

def updatingExcel(input):
    value = 'Hello World'
    sheet_ranges.range('H' + str(i + 3)).value = value
return value

    print(updatingExcel(anyinput)
```

I understand that if I run the.py file outside pycharm this issue most probably won't occur as the screen terminates itself. However I would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Use `app.activate` with `steal_focus=True`, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.App.activate

for example:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
wb.app.activate(steal_focus=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, I tried to use it as per documentation as below:

    xw.apps/activate(steal_focus=True)

but I get the following error:

" xw.apps/activate(steal_focus=True)
NameError: name 'activate' is not defined"

I am using Pycharm and when I use xw.apps in the list, there is no activate, only active. I have tried active, and it is not stealing the focus.

I am using all this in PC, and somehow I believe documentation refers to Mac, any idea where the problem might be?